# Implementation of QUEUE using Array

Tags: c++, queue

Implementation of QUEUE using Array in C++

There seems to be some problem with the Dequeue function.
Instead of deleting from front, it is deleting from rear..
I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_SIZE 101

int A[MAX_SIZE];
int front=-1,rear=-1;

void Enq(int x)
{ if (rear==(MAX_SIZE-1))
{return;}

if (front==-1 && rear==-1)
{front=rear=0;}

else { rear=rear+1;}

A[rear]=x;
}

void Deq()
{ if (front == -1 && rear == -1)
{return;}

else if(front == rear)
{
front = rear = -1;

}

else
front++;
}

void Print()
{ cout<<"Queue is: ";
 int count=(rear-front);
for(int i=0; i<=count; i++)
{ cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<"\n";
}

int main()
{ 
Enq(2); Print();
Enq(3); Print();
Enq(5); Print();
Deq();  Print();
Deq();  Print();
Enq(24); Print();
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
Success time: 0 memory: 3460 signal:0

Queue is: 2

Queue is: 2 3

Queue is: 2 3 5

Queue is: 2 3

Queue is: 2

Queue is: 2 3

Comment: Can you add the output?

Answer (score 0):

You are showing count elements, which is calculated as:

```
int count=(rear-front);
```

When you make

```
front++
```

You will just show one less element. But you always start at the position 0.

```
for(int i=0; i<=count; i++)
{ cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}
```

Maybe you should start from "front" and go up to "front+count"?

Keep in mind, trough, this implementation never really deletes anything, and you can just call Enq() MAX_SIZE times, no matter how many times you call Deq().

**EDIT**: If you want to be able to reuse spaces, you may add the element at the "front-1" position, and then do front--, only if front is >0.

Answer (score 0):

Use your front and rear variables:

```
for(int i=front; i<=rear; i++) { cout<<A[i]<<" ";}
```

I would implement it using pointers anyways.